# Rails: Export data in google spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-sheets, google-oauth

I am new to Rails and I want to export data to Google Spread Sheet from my web application.

1. I have created an app to get client id and client secret and enabled drive api for that.
2. I have installed google drive and google api client gem
3. And I used the code stated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-ruby)

This code successfully runs, open a new tab for authorization, and displays a code to paste. This is the point where I am stuck. The code that google authorization demands is in my controller code so my user can paste that code in my controller. I know its quiet stupid thing to ask but I am not finding a way to automatically get the code from api to further execution as we usually do in our facebook oauth applications. So can you guide me how to do it? The code looks like

```
def export_spred_sheet
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'google/api_client'
  require 'launchy'

  # Get your credentials from the console
  CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
  CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
  OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
  REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

  # Create a new API client & load the Google Drive API
  client = Google::APIClient.new
  drive = client.discovered_api('drive', 'v2')

  # Request authorization
  client.authorization.client_id = CLIENT_ID
  client.authorization.client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET
  client.authorization.scope = OAUTH_SCOPE
  client.authorization.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

  uri = client.authorization.authorization_uri
  Launchy.open(uri)

  # Exchange authorization code for access token
  $stdout.write  "Enter authorization code: "
  client.authorization.code = gets.chomp
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

  # Insert a file
  file = drive.files.insert.request_schema.new({
   'title' => 'My document',
   'description' => 'A test document',
   'mimeType' => 'text/plain'
 })

 media = Google::APIClient::UploadIO.new('document.txt', 'text/plain')
 result = client.execute(
   :api_method => drive.files.insert,
   :body_object => file,
   :media => media,
   :parameters => {
   'uploadType' => 'multipart',
   'alt' => 'json'})

  # Pretty print the API result
  jj result.data.to_hash
end
```

**Or is there any other way to do the task If I am on wrong track?**

Comment: Did you able to write data in spreadsheet? I am able to get access token but session.spreadsheets returns []

Comment: @Shweta, I wrote a gem recently for exporting your **ActiveRecord/Mongoid** model records to googlesheets: https://github.com/lakesare/model_to_googlesheet, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

I was also fighting against this in one of my project and finally I found soulution as follows:

Instead of using client ID and client secrete you can use P12 key generated in [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) under service account for authentication. In this case you won't need to paste any code in controller.

To generate p12 key

1. go to [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. then -> "APIs & Auth" -> "Credentials"
3. Create New Client ID of type 'Service Account'
4. Once new client Id generated. Under Service Account section you will find a button to 'generate new P12 key'. On click it will generate a p12 key. Download it and store it securely in your app and use it for authentication.

And use following code snippet to fetch access token.

```
key_file = p12_key_file_path
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(key_file, 'notasecret')
client = Google::APIClient.new application_name: "abcd", application_version: "1.0.0"
```

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID (used in following code snippet) will be Email address generated under this "Service Account" section in [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com).

```
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
    :token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics',
    :issuer => SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID,
    :access_type => 'offline',
    :signing_key => key
  )

  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
  client
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: getting insufficient permission :(

Comment: Can you please elaborate your error like at what point you got this error and please paste error message. Which api you wish to use. Please check if you have enabled that api on google developer console.